# Understanding member of array

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer

Is *member* concept applicable to an array (I.e. *member* of an array). Are elements and members of array the different concepts?

3.8/1 N3797:

> An object is said to have non-trivial initialization if it is of a
>   class or **aggregate** type and it or **one of its members** is initialized by
>   a constructor other than a trivial default constructor.
>
> [...]
>
> The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
>
> — storage with
>   the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
>
> — if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete

8.1/1 N3797:

> An aggregate is **an array** or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

3.8/2:

> [Note:The lifetime of an array object starts as soon as storage with
>   proper size and alignment is obtained, and its lifetime ends when the
>   storage which the array occupies is reused or released. 12.6.2
>   describes thelifetime of base and member subobjects. —end note]

So I suppose that elements of an array and members of an array are different concepts.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question?

Comment: "Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects*. A ubobject can be a *member subobject* (9.2), a *base class subobject* (Clause 10), or an *array element*." - so it's *element*, which is one type of *subobject*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of "member" as defined in the C++ standard:

> Members of a class are data members, member functions, nested types, and enumerators.
>
> §9.2 [class.mem]

Does not begin to apply to arrays since arrays are not of class type.